# FIO Flexible IO tester for repetitive data access patterns

Tags: linux, io, benchmarking

I am currently working on a project and I need to test my prototype with repetitive data access patterns. I came across fio which is a flexible I/O tester for Linux ([1](http://freecode.com/projects/fio)).

Fio has many options and I want it to produce a workload which accesses the same blocks of a file, the same number of times over and over again. I also need those accesses to not be equal among these blocks. For instance, if fio creates a file named "test.txt"
and this file is divided on 10 blocks, I need the workload to read a specific number of these blocks, with different number of IOs each, over and over again. Let's say that it chooses to access block 3, 7 and 9. Then I want to access these in a specific order and a specific number of times each, over and over again. If this workload can be described by N passes, then I want to be something like this:

1st pass: read block 3 10 times, read block 7 5 times, read block 9 2 times.

2nd pass: read block 3 10 times, read block 7 5 times, read block 9 2 times.

...

N-pass: read block 3 10 times, read block 7 5 times, read block 9 2 times.

Question 1: Can the above workload be produced with Fio? If yes, How?
Question 2: Is there a mailing list, forum, website, community for Fio users?

Thank you,
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http://www.spinics.net/lists/fio/index.html` This is the website you can follow mailing list.
`http://www.bluestop.org/fio/HOWTO.txt` link will also help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite a tricky thing to do. The closest you'll get with parameters is using one of the non-uniform distributions (see `random_distribution` in the [HOWTO](https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/master/HOWTO)) but you'll be saying re-read blocks A, B, C more than blocks X, Y, Z and you won't be able to control the exact counts.

An alternative is to write an iolog that can be replayed that has the exact sequence you're looking for (see Trace file format v2 in the HOWTO).